# Can local javascript variables be read by user console?

Tags: javascript, dom, scope, namespaces

I am trying to create an online lottery system in which user has to guess a number between 1 to 10. If the number matches with the javascript generate random number he will win the lottery. The method I used is:

```js
!function(){
  var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10));
  var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
  btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var user_input = document.getElementById("text").value;
    if( user_input == x) {
      alert("Won Lottery", user_input, x);
    }
    else {
      alert(user_input + x + "sorry");
    }
  });
}();
```

```html
<h2>Guess a number between 1 and 10 </h2>  
<input id="text" type="text">
<button id="btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

My question is, can a hacker open the js console and somehow find the value of local `x` variable?

Comment: Yes. The person in control of the browser can see all your code and manipulate any value. (In this case it would be a little tricky, but the basic point is that you can't trust the browser at all; you can't even guarantee that the client *is* a browser.)

Comment: @Pointy How can he access `x` variable? It isn't global so that he could read it with `window.x`.

Comment: you could just put a breakpoint on it to pause the execution when x is in scope

Comment: The browser user can equip their browser with arbitrary extension code and manipulate your JavaScript before it even runs. Now that may be pointless if there's ultimately no server interaction and it's just an in-browser game of course.

Comment: @scoon1329 I don't know about breakpoints in javascript.

Comment: nope ( not that easy) but he can *alert("Won Lottery")*

Comment: Than learn about your console tools.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

At this point in the code execution, x is within scope. You can see in the right column that x = 0 so it's just a case of changing user_input to 0 and then finishing the execution.